# What is the right approach of defining sequelize associations without using sequelize.sync?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

The project:
Language: NodeJS,
Database: Postgres,
ORM: Sequelize v6

I've opted out of using `sequelize.sync`.
Instead, I am using migrations to create/update database schema.
I define associations in model definition files.
The part that confuses me, is the references option in model creation migrations.
The documentation is unclear about this option (and for the general use-case without `sequelize.sync` as well).

[image]

The main questions are:

1. Is the references option required in my specific use case?
2. is the references option recommended in my specific use case?
3. In which case would I possibly need this option?
4. What is the proper way to manage  associations in my specific use case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After some research (observing database changes using different approaches), trial and error I figured out that it's not possible to add configurable constraints (for example specifying `onDelete` action) with only `references` option.

So it seems the right way to implement associations is as follows:
(Note: without using `sequelize.sync`)

1. Create `table1` using a migration
2. Create `table2` using a migration - **without specifying `references` option**
3. Inside the migration (creation) file of the `table2` add the following code (with necessary changes) to add a foreign key constraint

```
await queryInterface.addConstraint('tableName', {
  fields: ['some-table2-field'],
  type: 'foreign key',
  references: {
    table: 'table1',
    field: 'table1Field',
  },
  onDelete: 'cascade',
  onUpdate: 'no action',
});
```

4. Define association in table1 and table2 models as it's usually done, eg.

```
// table1.model.js


table1.hasMany(models.table2, {
    foreignKey: 'name-of-the-key',
    onDelete: 'cascade',
    onUpdate: 'no action',
});


// table2.model.js

table2.belongsTo(models.table1, {
    foreignKey: 'name-of-the-key',
    onDelete: 'cascade',
    onUpdate: 'no action',
});
```

So to answer my questions 1-3: you practically don't need to use `references` when using migrations over `sequelize.sync`, and 4: was described above.

If someone else has a better or more correct approach, answers and comments are welcome.